# setState triggers props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Examples component receives data (a list of examples) from the Definition component. Since these examples can be edited by the user, they are placed in a state-form, the state form also allows us to create/delete additional fields each time the state is changing.

The state is changed at every keystroke on an input (handleChangeExample function), but it seems that the properties (props.examples) are also updated as well, and I can't figure why it does that.

I believe that the Examples component properties should remain immutable/unchanged during the whole cycle, unless we explicitly save the block (saveBlock function), which triggers in turn the saveExamples function from the parent-Definition component.

```
var Examples = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            examples: this.props.examples
        }
    },

    editBlock: function(event) {
//        this.setState({examples: this.props.examples});
        this.setState({editingBlock: !this.state.editingBlock});
    },

    saveBlock: function(event) {
        var that = this;
        var filtered_examples = [];

        this.state.examples.forEach(function(example) {
            if (example !== '') {
                filtered_examples.push(example);
            }
        });

        this.props.saveExamples(filtered_examples);
    },

    handleChangeExample: function(i) {
        var updated_examples = this.state.examples;
        updated_examples[i] = this.refs['example_' + i].getDOMNode().value.trim();

        this.setState({examples: updated_examples});
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var fields = {};

        console.log(this.props.examples);
        console.log(this.state.examples);

        this.state.examples.forEach(function(example, i) {
            if (example !== '') {
                fields['example-' + i] =
                    <li className='editing__entry'>
                        <input type='text'
                               key={i}
                               ref={'example_' + i}
                               onChange={that.handleChangeExample.bind(null, i)}
                               defaultValue={example} />
                    </li>;
            }
        });

        fields['example-' + (this.state.examples.length+1)] =
            <li className='editing__entry'>
                <input type='text'
                       key={this.state.examples.length+1}
                       ref={'example_' + (this.state.examples.length+1)}
                       onChange={that.handleChangeExample.bind(null, (this.state.examples.length+1))}
                       defaultValue='' />
            </li>;

        return (
            <section className='definition__examples block'>
                    <div className='editing'>
                        <ul className='editing__fields'>
                            {fields}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            <button onClick={this.saveBlock} className='button--primary--small'>Save changes</button>

            </section>
        );
    }
});


var Definition = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            examples: this.props.definition.examples
        }
    },

    saveExamples: function(examples) {
        this.setState({examples: examples});
    },


    render: function() {
        var editingMode = this.props.editingMode;
        var object = this;

        return (
            <li className='definition'>
            <Examples editingMode={editingMode}
                      examples={this.state.examples}
                      saveExamples={this.saveExamples} />
            </li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Definition;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because `this.state.examples` is just a reference to `this.props.examples`.

`this.props.examples` is being updated for the same reason that this is the expected behavior in plain JavaScript:

```
> var a = [ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ];
undefined
> a
[ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ]
> var b = a;
undefined
> b
[ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ]
> b[1] = 'DEF';
'DEF'
> b
[ 'abc', 'DEF', 'ghi' ]
> a
[ 'abc', 'DEF', 'ghi' ]
```

There are a couple ways around this. One is to create a copy of the `this.props.examples` and set that into `this.state.examples` (you can do this via Array.prototype.slice):

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        examples: this.props.examples.slice()
    }
}
```

I think this will work in your case because `examples` is just an Array of strings. However, `slice` will only create a shallow copy of the Array so if the elements were objects or arrays, you'd still end up updating `this.props.examples`.

The other option is to use [Immutability Helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to update your state. You may also want to take a look at [immutable-js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js).

Here is a simplified example how to do what you are trying to do but with Immutability Helpers: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljqqer3e/4/).

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var SomeComponent = React.createClass( {

  getInitialState : function() {
      return {
          examples : this.props.examples,
      }
  },
  _handleChange : function( index, e) {
      var updateObj = {};
      updateObj[ index ] =  { $set : e.target.value };

      var newData = React.addons.update( this.state.examples, updateObj );

      this.setState( { examples : newData } );
  },

  render : function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this, 0)}/><br/>
        <input onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this, 1)}/><br/>
        props:
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.examples,null,2)}</pre>
        state:
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.examples,null,2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
} );

React.renderComponent(<SomeComponent examples={ [ "ABC", "DEF" ] } />, document.getElementById( 'main' ) );
```